# jQuery execute on click not on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im currently doing an `onclick` event, where the user is redirected to a new site.

Unfortunly, when I click on the input located in class `side` , it fires the event, while im acually looking for it to not do the event while clicking / typing in the input field.

**Q: How can I make the jQuery code not fire when clicking on the input field?**

```
<div id="<?echo $ar['url'];?>" class="mobile-no-margin upgradeable  full-mobile col-sm-12" style=" background-size: 100% 100%; background-image: url(test">
   <div class="side">
       <input type="input" name="<? echo $ar['input'];?>" class="col-sm-12">
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".upgradeable").on('click',function(e) {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        url(id);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you looking for it to do? When to you want to fire that event?

Comment: @dane, i only want it to fire when i click on the .upgradeable div ( or any child elements), i just dont want it to fire when clicking on the input field.

Comment: check using [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) if the div was click or other element...

Comment: the click on the input is bubbling up to the outer div. cancel the bubble `$(div.side input).on('click', function (e) {e.stopPropagation()})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$(".upgradeable").on('click',function(e) {
var target = $( e.target );
  if ( !target.is( ".side" ) ) {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        url(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: to be correct if ( !target.is( ".side input" ) ) {

but thanks!

Comment: waiting for it to allow me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourelement).click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); // Stop the click 
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/